# Spring Security 4 JSF Managed bean preauthorize annotation

Tags: jsf, spring-security, authorization

I am hoping that someone can help me with integrating the @PreAuthorize annotation with managed beans. I have been trying to get this to work for the last few hours but apparently there is something I am missing. My research on the web has shown that the global-method-security element can be used with spring or with aspectj. Since I don't want to declare my managed beans as spring beans I have chosen to use aspectj. For some reason though the PreAuthorize annotation is completely ignored. I am not getting any errors and everything compiles and runs fine but there is no security check on the managed bean. Apparently aspectj requires some kind of weaving??? Maybe I am approaching this wrong way and there is an easier way..not sure. Using Tomcat 7 with JSF 2.2 and Spring Security 4. I have the annotation on the class but that may be my problem. I am under the assumption that putting it on the class will use its default constructor method.

Can someone please advise? (configs below)

security.xml

```
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
     xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
    <headers>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </headers>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('Admin')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/cms/**" access="hasAnyRole('Admin','CMS_Admin')" />
    <form-login login-page='/login' default-target-url="/" />
    <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/" />
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<b:bean name="bcryptEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
<b:bean name="iberisUserDetailsService" class="com.bizznetworxonline.iberis.core.web.controllers.admin.security.IberisUserDetailsService"/>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='iberisUserDetailsService'>
        <password-encoder ref="bcryptEncoder"/>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<global-method-security mode="aspectj" pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class="true">
</global-method-security>

</b:beans>
```

Maven build

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

Managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('Admin')")
public class ProductManagement
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're instructing JSF to create your bean and not Spring, `@PreAuthorize` makes little sense there. Even when using Spring to create the bean, its use is targeted to methods (even if you can annotate a class to have all its methods processed):

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public void create(Contact contact);
```

Here Spring checks if the current logged user has the USER Role, in order for him to be able to create a contact.

It seems what you want to restrict in your question is the access to a whole view, so why not go the same way as you do in your security.xml declaration?

```
<intercept-url pattern="/products/product_management.xhtml" access="hasRole('USER')" />
```

This way Spring security checks the permission in its Web Filter, which is even better.

See also:

- [Expression-Based Access Control](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html)

Comment: I was hoping it would block the constructor call when declared at the class level. I tried it on a specific method and its still doesn't work. Its okay though cuz I think i am going about this in the wrong way like you said. I will stick to the out of the box intercept-url and then create my own little security util class to perform checks on certain methods. I think that will give me more refined control. That way i can put permissions in my database based on roles. The less fighting with spring security the better.

Comment: @user2677597 I've slightly changed my answer to explain the issue better. As I said, there's no chance of using spring annotations in a JSF bean. You could still turn it in a Spring bean (see the spring docs, the part of integration with other frameworks). If you go that way you'll have to implement your custom scope to emulate the JSF view scope, but you already have some implementations done in the Internet.

Comment: @user2677597 Did you solved it? What you did do to get annotation level at managed beans method?